# I want to specific a host of http request, can Greasemonkey help me to do this job?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I have search "DNS" and "host" in userscripts.org, but I can't found my answer.

Sometimes I want to do some test in my development enviroment, for example,
192.168.22.11  testfunc.myDomain.com

But I don't want to change the C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file all the time and restart my browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is not clear.

You want to locally reroute `myDomain.com` to 192.168.22.11?

Greasemonkey can automatically reload pages, changing the server or IP, but I don't recommend that.  It would be a messy endeavor -- especially handling all the `href` and `src` attributes, etc.

If I read the question correctly, the [Redirector add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/redirector/) would be a better fit.

~~~
**HOWEVER**, the proper way to do this is to structure your site and your apps so that everything uses relative addresses, AMAP.  Use a single bit of code to detect the running server, once per request (or once per app init), and to set a `<base>` element and/or an appropriate global variable.

The point is that our code runs without any changes whether it's dropped on *ProductionServer.com*, or *TestServer.com*, or `192.168.22.11`.  So, there is no need for redirects, or even slight modifications between test code and production code.